# how can i create unit test with not found exception?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, testing, controller

here i have a test to test the controller, i was succes to test create and findByName succesfully, and i want to add test with findByName_notFound but i don't understand yet to make it.

here my code :

```
@Test
public void shouldRegisterNewStudent() throws Exception {
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setId(1);
    student.setParentsName("farizan");
    student.setParentsMobile("8465");
    student.setName("sahru");
    student.setClassroom(null);
    student.setNote("free text");
    Mockito.when(studentService.save(student)).thenReturn(student);

    mockMvc.perform(post("/register")
            .contentType("application/json")
            .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(student)))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated());
}
@Test
public void findStudentByName()throws Exception{
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setId(1);
    student.setParentsName("farizan");
    student.setParentsMobile("8465");
    student.setName("sahru");
    student.setClassroom(null);
    student.setNote("free text");
    final String name = "sahru";
    given(studentService.findByName("sahru")).willReturn(student);
    mockMvc.perform(get("/findByName/{name}",name)
            .contentType("application/json")
            .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(student)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
@Test
public void findStudentByName_notFound()throws Exception{
    final String name = "sahru";
    given(studentService.findByName("sarah")).willReturn((Student) Collections.emptyList());
    mockMvc.perform(get("/findByName/{name}",name)
            .contentType("application/json"))
            .andExpect(status().isNotFound());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tutorial for [Testing Exceptions with Spring MockMvc](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-test-exceptions)

Comment: That's not an answer; instead it'd be better as a comment for OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rest-assured` library to test rest APIs, it easy to use and powerful.

Steps:

1. *Include dependency with your build tool , with maven like :*

   ```
        <dependency>
           <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
           <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
           <version>3.0.5</version>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
   ```
2. Create a springboot test as follows:

   ```
   @LocalServerPort
   private int port;

   @Test
   public void test() {
       RestAssured.given()
               .port(port)
               .get("/test/api") //your endpoint
               .then()
               .assertThat()
               .statusCode(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
    }
   }
   ```